# Application not Authorized to access restricted API (J2ME)

Tags: java, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm coding an SMS application in J2ME and on the server side of the application the line below throws the exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Application not authorized to access the restricted API

This is the offending line of code:

```
sender = Sender.getSInstance();
```

Comment: emulator. Here is the getSInstance method:
public static Sender getSInstance() {
        if(instance == null)instance = new Sender();
        return instance;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:[Understanding MIDP 2.0's Security Architecture](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/). It might help you.
Also read [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/228905/JME/Mobile/java-lang-SecurityException).

Comment: I have no idea where to begin looking for my security xml document.

Comment: No luck. I'm using netbeans and I looked in the netbeans folder as well nothing

Comment: @Andre: Try this:http://developers.sun.com/mobility/reference/techart/nbmp40-security.html